# Rails nested join with conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have the following join tables and (relevant models and tables)

- roles_users : user_id, role_id
- permissions_roles : role_id, permission_id, object_id, object_type

For a given user, permission and object, I would like to like to find if user has an associated permission for an object via its roles.

Any help with the relevant query would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User

  def has_permission?(permission, object)
    RoleUser.joins(:permission_roles).where(
      :roles_users      => {
        :user_id       => id
      },
      :permission_roles => {
        :permission_id => permission,
        :object_type   => object.class.base_class.name,
        :object_id     => object
      }
    ).exists?
  end
end
```

Now you can check the permission as follows:

```
current_user.has_permission?(@edit_permission, @blog_post)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the user and the object, how about this:

```
allowed = user.roles.joins(:permissions => :object).where(:object => { :id => object.id }).any?
```